# Python Dictionary min max

Tags: python, dictionary, max, min

I have a question regarding this code: The number of elements in the dict vary at every iteration:

```
d["one"] = 12
d["two"] = 13
d["three"] = 14

maxkey, maxvalue = max(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
minkey, minvalue = min(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

if the values for "one" "twor" etc. are different, everything is OK.

Now assume the following:

```
d["one"] = 13
d["two"] = 13


maxkey, maxvalue = max(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
minkey, minvalue = min(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

I want the following result: If the values are equal, then minkey, minvalue should be not the same as maxkey, maxvalue (it should be the other entry/or one of the others if there are several equal entries). Is there a simple way of implementing that in Python? Thank you very much for your help

Example:

```
d["one"] = 12
d["two"] = 12
d["three"] = 12
minkey, minvalue = min(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
maxkey, maxvalue = max(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Result

```
minkey = "three"
maxkey = "three"
```

but I want, if

```
minkey = "three"
```

then maxkey should be

```
maxkey = "one"
```

or

```
maxkey = "two"
```

Comment: Could you please give an example for the dedicated/desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take key into consideration when finding min & max (with lower priority):

```
maxkey, maxvalue = max(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
minkey, minvalue = min(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

So when finding extremes I do not compare dict *values* only, but `(value, key)` tuple. Tuples are compared first by the first element, i.e. given tuples `T1` and `T2`, first `T1[0]` compared to `T2[0]`. If `T1[0]==T2[0]`, then second elements are compared: `T1[1]` and `T2[1]`. So, in my case, dict keys are compared, if values are equal, i.e. keys are compared with lower priority

Comment: Great, thank you very much, it works! Could you explain what that mean what that mean "with lower priority"?

Comment: I've added more info

Answer (score 2):

You can change the line with mins to

```
minkey, minvalue = min(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1] if x[0] != maxkey else float('inf'))
```

I changed the lambda expression so that it returns infinity if the key is the same as the maxkey (so it will never be a minimal value). This won't work however if there is only 1 pair of elements in the dictionary, but that can be easily fixed with an if.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But i would like that it returns one of the other entries - like in the example above. Is that possible?

Comment: It will return one of the other entries. Check out Lol4t0's answer, though. It is a bit more elegant (although a little less efficient)